# find a point in 3D space

Tags: geometry, 3d, triangulation

Suppose we have $3$ fixed points $P_1, P_2, P_3$ in $3$-D space, their coordinates are $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$ for $i=1,2,3$. The problem is to find a point $P$ so that the distances from $P$ to $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are $d_1,d_2,d_3$, respectively.

Comment: I understand there should be two such points, in general.

Comment: are $d_1, d_2, d_3$ given? if so, a counterexample would be $P_1 = (0,0,1)$, $P_2 = (0,1,0)$, $P_3 = (1,0,0)$ and $d_1 = 10000$, $d_2, = 0$, $d_3, = \text{anything}$. If the $d_i$ can be anything, then this is obviously true.

Comment: If the point does exist, the set of all of them would be the set formed by the intersection of the 3 sphere of radius $d_1, d_2, d_3$ centered at the respective points.

Comment: The number of solution points could be zero, one, two, or infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Look at all the points that are at distance $d_1$ from first point and $d_2$ from second point. These points must satisfy
$$\left(z-{\it z_1}\right)^2+\left(y-{\it y_1}\right)^2+\left(x-
 {\it x_1}\right)^2-{\it d_1}^2=0\\
\left(z-{\it z_2}\right)^2+\left(y-{\it y_2}\right)^2+\left(x-
 {\it x_2}\right)^2-{\it d_2}^2=0$$
If you subtract the two equations, you will get a linear equation.

Do the same taking it pairwise and solve.

Forgot to add this:
If you do the above you will have 3 linear equations but only two are independent. So, solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$ from these two. Then substitute in any of the equation to get a quadratic in $z$. Solve for $z$ and use it to get $x$ and $y$. As was pointed out, you will usually have two solutions.